# Generic method with delegate type

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

My objective is demostrated with the following code:

```
void MyMethod<T>(T aMethod, params object[] aParams) where T: System.Delegate
{
    aMethod.Invoke(aParams);
}
```

How can I do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Unconstrained Melody](http://unconstrained-melody.googlecode.com) - or pinch the bit which allows this.

On the other hand, that's not actually going to expose an `Invoke` method anyway. What do you want to do which can't be done with:

```
void MyMethod(Delegate aMethod, params object[] aParams)
{
    aMethod.DynamicInvoke(aParams);
}
```

? I mean, you wouldn't actually have compile-time safety even with the generic version, as the parameters could be of the wrong types etc.

Comment: I was hoping to get parameter type safety somehow.

Comment: @Max: Why not just invoke the method directly then? I don't see what this is really buying you.

Comment: I want to extract common exception handling code. try { invoke } catch(1) {}  catch(2) {} ...

Comment: One situation where a generic constraint would be helpful would be writing a type-safe delegate-combining extension method versions of `Delegate.Combine` and `Delegate.Remove` (given `Action<SomeDerivedType> Act1` and `Action<SomeBaseType>Act2`, it would be nice if `Act1.Plus(Act2)` could yield an `Action<SomeDerivedType>` containing both delegates (converting the second delegate if need be).  I can't figure out a way to have the method know the compile-time type of `Act1` without having Intellisense offer the `Plus` method on arbitrary class objects.

Comment: @supercat: Yup, I think Unconstrained Melody could do that...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish:  Since only the compiler or runtime can inherit from System.Delegate, what point does the generic have over:

```
void MyMethod<T>(System.Delegate aMethod, params object[] aParams) 
{
  aMethod.DynamicInvoke(aParams);
}
```

Now, if you're trying to do something tricky with delegate type constraints, you can look at http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/ , which does some il rewriting to allow you to do it.

Or, just use an `Action<object[]>`  - or lots of overloads with `Action<T>`, `Action<T1,T2>`, etc.

```
void MyMethod(Action<object[]> aMethod, params object[] aParams)
{
   aMethod(aParams);
} 

//or
void MyMethod<T>(Action<T> aMethod, T param)
{
   aMethod(param);
} 

void MyMethod<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> aMethod, T1 param1, T2 param2)
{
   aMethod(param1, param2);
}
```

I don't really like the huge list of overloads, but in some cases they provide the best library usability.

Answer (score 0):

`T` must be a type, but you don't need any generics

```
void MyMethod(Action<object[]> aMethod, params object[] aParams)
{
    aMethod(aParams);
}

void Print(params object[] output)
{
    foreach (var o in output)
        Console.WriteLine(o);
}
```

call it like this:

```
MyMethod(Print, 1, "Hello");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for delegates with no parameters (MethodInvoker).